# Three Dimensional Routing Input Location Errors and Questions, ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d, network, routing

I am having a bit of a problem with my three dimensional route solving. I am creating an interior building network, and ideally would be routing from room to room. I created a line feature class, with z values, implemented it into a network dataset. I built a model that was successfully routing in ArcScene, but something has broken. Whenever I click to interactively add a set of stops to find a route the first one returns as successful but the second one always is returned as an error. The routing does not function if the two stops are not placed on the same line segment, or across a break (simple vertex, or another adjoining segment).

I was also wondering if there was a way to potentially add stops by defining it based on an attribute from a point class that is contained in the network, rather than clicking interactively? I do not wish to add an entire point feature class, just specific points from one.

If anyone has any ideas, they would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I am using ArcGIS 10.